# External hard drive spinning but not on disk management

Tags: hard-drive

I have a external hard drive on my computer that I have had for 8-10 years, and slowly it has stopped working. Today I tried to back it up, and about 1/3 way through copying to another drive I got a error and so I wiped the drive I was copying to and tried again. When I tried again the old drive would disconnect while I was trying to copy and eventually the drive would show up but when I tried to open a file on it it would disconnect. Now I can hear the drive spinning and the head moving around but it doesn't show up on disk manager. How can I get it so I can at least get the data off?

Comment: This is a tough problem to solve online or via tools, as you have to check both hardware and software to see where the issue is. But given your symptoms it seems like the hdd is failing.

Comment: Would you say the driver board is dying or something else?